# Power Tools - Page Publisher Timeout

Tags: 2011, powertools

I'm publishing a fair few pages via the Page Publisher Power Tool and I keep getting a timeout message:

> Page publishing failed, reason Transaction Timeout

I know these things use web services behind the scenes. Is there a way I can increase the timeout value?

Comment: how many is 'fair few' :) - i've seen better results when publishing smaller sections of sites

Comment: Can you see any events which match these timeouts in the logs on the server, or on the database?

Answer (score 3):

This Powertool uses the Core Service, which is just a WCF web service.  Here is an answer for managing timeout settings of those - basically you can't do it via generic WCF configs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943935/how-to-limit-a-request-execution-time-of-wcf-service/2944969#2944969

Other than that, try playing around with the timeout values in the Tridion CM Snap-in:

[image]